# Splitting boxes to 50% height of their parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I would like to split the active items to 50% height of their parent element. So when I open the first two items, they should split to 50% of their parent class `.items` (both .item have 100px). So I can see both without scrolling. Also when I open all three of them, they should get the height of 100px, which is the half of their parent. My problem is, tha the second item overlaps and I have to scroll. Whats wrong?

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.itemList = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Item 1",
    isOpen: false
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Item 2",
    isOpen: false
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Item 3",
    isOpen: false
  }];

  $scope.setHeight = function() {
    if ($scope.itemList.length > 1) {
      var typeHeaderHeight = $('.item-header').outerHeight();
      var halfHeight = Math.round($('.items').outerHeight() / 2);

      setTimeout(() => {
        $('.item').css('height', typeHeaderHeight);
        $('.item.active').css('height', halfHeight);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.frame {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 200px;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  color: white;
}

.item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.active {
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
  color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="frame" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in itemList" ng-click="item.isOpen = !item.isOpen; setHeight()" ng-class="{active: item.isOpen}">
      <div class="item-header">
        {{item.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are setting the values of `typeHeaderHeight` and `halfHeight` variables outside the timeout so it always calculated before the item is actually opened so there is mistake in the calculations

try to make it like

```js
   
   

      setTimeout(() => {
      var typeHeaderHeight = $('.item-header').outerHeight();
      var halfHeight = Math.round($('.items').outerHeight() / 2);
     
        $('.item').css('height', typeHeaderHeight);
        $('.item.active').css('height', halfHeight);
      });
    },500)
```

One more thing .. I don't recommend to use setTimeout of vanilla JavaScript try to use `$timeout` instead of it